# Raw Input for mouse tracking always returns 0 for delta values

Tags: c++, winapi, raw-input

Registered Raw Input Device doesn't give mouse delta, `WM_INPUT` does get triggered and it does pass the `if(raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE)` statement, but values given are always 0

```
void InputSetup() {
    RAWINPUTDEVICE rid;
    rid.usUsagePage = HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC;       //0x01
    rid.usUsage = HID_USAGE_GENERIC_MOUSE;          //0x02
    rid.dwFlags = RIDEV_INPUTSINK;                  //0x00000100
    rid.hwndTarget = hWnd_main;                     //Window Handle
    RegisterRawInputDevices(&rid, 1, sizeof(rid));  //Registring RID
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    switch(uMsg){
        //...
        case WM_INPUT:
            UINT dwSize = 40;
            static BYTE lpb[40];

            GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, lpb, &dwSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));

            RAWINPUT* raw = (RAWINPUT*)lpb;

            if (raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE) {
                MouseDelta.x = raw->data.mouse.lLastX;
                MouseDelta.y = raw->data.mouse.lLastY;
            }
            break;
        //...
    }
}
```

`MouseDelta` Is always `(0, 0)`. The WM_INPUT does trigger, but `raw->data.mouse.lLastX` and `Y` are always 0.

Comment: What is the value of `raw->data.mouse.usFlags` when `lLastX`/`Y` are 0?

Comment: You seem to be requesting 40 bytes, which doesn't quite add up to `sizeof(RAWINPUT)`. A better way to do this would be to pass the address of a local `RAWINPUT` object alongside its true size. Don't forget to add a scope inside your `case` label; your compiler did warn you about this.

Comment: See [Using Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/using-raw-input) to call correctly **GetRawInputData**

Comment: @IInspectable case label is in my code just didn't copy it because it seemed to clutter the code. Oops, first time using SO. The thing you the first part of your response did the job. Thanks it fixed the problem, i just copied that from msdn so I thought it wasn't the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright guys the problem were these lines:

```
UINT dwSize = 40;
static BYTE lpb[40];
```

just set them both to sizeof(RAWINPUT) and it will work
I got that from msdn article but it turns out it was wrong

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not enough. You actually really *need* to construct a local `RAWINPUT` object (in place of `lpb`), and pass its address into `GetRawInputData`. A `RAWINPUT` structure has (potentially) stricter alignment requirements than an array of `BYTE`s. Accessing the pointer `raw` from `RAWINPUT* raw = (RAWINPUT*)lpb` exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: "I got that from msdn article" - can you provide a link to the erroneous MSDN article?

Comment: The article that says to use `40` is [Taking Advantage of High-Definition Mouse Movement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/taking-advantage-of-high-dpi-mouse-movement).